# Make flip flop wider

Tags: tikz-pgf, logic, circuits

[image]

Im having problems creating a schematic like this one for my school project. I know how to insert the parts, but this flip flop is much wider than the one I inserted. Does anyone know how to make it wider?
My current ff: 
[image]

The new style i defined

```
\tikzset{flipflop SR/.style={
flipflop, 
scale=0.65,
flipflop def={
    t1=\textsl{S},
    t2=\textsl{CP}, 
    t3=\textsl{R}, 
    t6=\textsl{Q}, 
    t4={\textsl{\ctikztextnot{Q}}}
 }
}}
```

The env. in the body

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit logic US]
    \node[flipflop SR](ff1) at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The heights are matching but the width isn't the same...

Comment: Could you please show us the code for your current results? This way anybody trying to help you doesn't have to have a fresh start but can build upon your code.

Comment: I edited the main post

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using a dipchip and modifying it to my needs

```
\begin{circuitikz}[circuit logic US, every circuit symbol/.style={scale=0.65}]
\node[
        dipchip,
        num pins=6,
        hide numbers,
        no topmark,
        external pins width=0](ff1) at (3.5,0)      {};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 1) {\textsl{S}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 2) {\textsl{CP}};
    \node [right,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 3) {\textsl{R}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 6) {\textsl{Q}};
    \node [left,font=\tiny] at (ff1.bpin 4) {\textsl{\ctikztextnot{Q}}};
\end{circuitikz}
```

In the preamble i added the modifications

```
\ctikzset{multipoles/dipchip/width=1}
\ctikzset{multipoles/thickness=0.5}
```

This is the only way to make custom elements like this.

This is the result:

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the `circuititkz` library with the internal Ti*k*Z circuit library.

In `circuitikz`:

1. to change the scale of the flipflop, use `\ctikzset{flipflops/scale=0.7}` (better than use plain `scale`, which will affect *everything but the line thickness*, including the texts;
2. To change the width alone, for example to have a squatty one, use `\circuitikz{multipoles/flipflop/width=1.6}`

You can find it described in a the section "Flip-flops customizations" in the manual, around page 117.